# Under which category does the images fall in the MVC model?

Tags: ios

The images that are added into the iOS App oder which category of the MVC model do they fall into?

When we store data in our App, it's the model and the UI elements fall into the View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. Images are probably both part of the model and the view. Technically the model is storing the bytes of the images and the view is taking those bytes and turning them into actual images you can see. So maybe it's more accurate to say that certain aspects of the images are in the model and others are in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Images themselves aren't a part the MVC pattern. The **process** of taking a image from storage to the user's screen is. The sub-process that takes the image from storage to memory would be apart of the **model**. The part that takes the memory and show's (usually in a `UIViewController`) it in the view is the **controller**, and the `UIImageView` that handles presenting / rendering the image to the screen is part of the **view**.